# Stylize scientific plots

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketching

I am preparing illustrations for a scientific publication. As a direct result of calculations I obtain figures (raster format) as depicted in the first row below. Now journals are full of these kind of plots, which to my opinion do not convey much information and not actually deserve to be depicted in color. Therefore I decided to stylize these images in AI by tracing them in 3 colors (second row).
[image]

It is quite common in this field, however, to make even more stylised plots as shown below
[image]
[image]

While I probably can draw diagrams like that in AI directly, I would like to base them on the realistic data (Fig.1). Therefore my question: How can I stylize the diagrams on Fig.1 (second row) even more, in order to create a recognisable picture with minimum of elements and colours?

**In response to some comments.** I did try to trace to contours, etc.

[image]

However, it is a lot of manual work and it is just repeating someone's style...

Comment: Have you thought of using tints of your existing colors? Unimportant sections could be 30-50% tint of each color, so the full strength colors stand out more. That will not add colors for printing.

Comment: @Christy I will try your idea. How to do it most straightforwardly in AI?

Comment: A very quick idea (and therefore not a full answer) would be to livetrace the raster images with a setting that turns it into a line drawing.

Comment: Well i would just change the shader code in the 3d  model to be honest. If you really need vectors then i would trace those areas afterwards.

Comment: @Vincent thank you for your suggestion. Tried to implement it (see my edit). It is ok, but just I feel this way I copy someone's style. I would prefer to have a different and possible distinct stylization   .

Comment: @yarchik consider a different angle that should provide adequate difference. Make the hatch lighter and the edges thicker would be a good idea.

Comment: @yarchik Are you still using Illustrator, or have you worked it out in another program? If you're using Ai, once you've traced, then expanded the trace, you could make your colors into spot colors, and then it's fairly simple to direct select (white arrow tool) some of the objects to change to 50% tints.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the radio silence, crazy deadline.

What I meant was this:

starting from the vector image in Illustrator. (For this, I rebuilt it very quickly.)

I created swatches for your two colors, but you can use pantone colors if you wish. With an object selected, click and drag the color from the box at the top left corner into the swatches palette.

[image]

I next converted the swatches to Spot Colors: double-click the swatch in the palette, and change Color type to Spot Color, and I usually change color mode to CMYK.
[image]
You can see it worked if your swatches now have a little black dot on the corner.
[image]
Then, depending on which items you want to change, I selected the two opposite branches and changed the spot color tint to 50%. 
[image]
This is not a transparency, so remember that it will knock out background colors and images, like below. 
[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Christy. It is not exactly what I was expecting, but it made me thinking broader.